# Pi camera not working

Tags: camera, pi-zero-w, mmal

I just got my Pi camera v2.1, took 1 test photo and 2 test videos, when I wanted to record another vid (10s) it was 1kb so I tried `raspistill` and got

```
mmal: No data received from sensor. Check all connections, including the Sunny one on the camera board
```

`vcgencmd get_camera` shows `supported=1 detected=1`

since then camera doesnt work :/

I'm running RPI Zero W with raspbian (2017-04-10), the camera module is v2.1, psu is 5V 2A so it shouldnt be a problem

things that I tried/checked:

- `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- camera is enabled in `raspi-config`
- tried reboots, even reinstalled whole raspbian
- tested continuity of cable connecting pi to camera - all ok
- reconnected everything, also sunny connector on camera board
- both csi connectors seems to be soldered properly

I dont have any other RPI/camera/csi cable to swap and try

I googled for this problem and didn't rly find anything other than "check connections" and "yep, its not working - but a new one"

so, is there something else I can do/try or should I try call the store where I bought camera to try get new one ?

**Edit :**
I send camera to seller (didnt say anything about it was working at first), seller sent me new one

Comment: only lines in `/boot/config.txt` that are uncommented are 
`dtparam=audio=on
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128`
every thing else is commented

Comment: Sounds like you've tried everything in which case it may well be a dead camera now. Bear in mind they are static sensitive - I'd recommend getting some sort of case for it if you can.

Comment: @DaveJones so I have another silly question - should I mention to seller that camera was working for a while or its better to say it was dead from the beginning ?

Comment: You can if you like, but they'll probably form the opinion, that the camera was most likely damaged through static discharge (ie user error) which would probably invalidate any warranty (I'm afraid this is the most likely scenario)

Comment: @DaveJones so, you are telling me it would be "better" if camera was damaged in other way - like connecting it to 12v so it would be completely dead ? and then playing "dumb" while talking to seller ?

how to protect from esd in future ? because if camera was laying on sth it was either on paper envelope or box that camera came in, and I grabbed camera only from sides to not touch anything on pcb so I'm quite surprised how it got damaged... in that case will cheapest camera mounts from aliexpress be safe to use ?

Comment: How you deal with the distributor I leave to your own conscience. As to how to protect the camera I've generally found one of the issues was users accidentally resting the camera on the GPIO pins (including the 5v ones) which probably isn't a good idea (we had several die during various picademy sessions, most likely through mishandling). I think even the cheapest camera case is likely a good idea as it'll facilitate safe handling (though this is entirely a guess on my part)

Comment: @DaveJones, do you know by chance if and what temperature can affect camera work ? I am planning to use camera for 24/7 streaming (kind of IP cam), temperature range I think will be from ~-30C(but haven't seen that low from years) to +whatever it can be in summer in full sun, should I be worried ? camera will be ofc in some kind of waterproof case and sun wont be shining directly into camera itself but on its case so it can probably get hot

Answer (score 1):

Burnt camera module. Happened to me once, I had killed the cam although I was super careful.I ran all troubleshooting possible. Apparently, it got fried when I pulled it out while the pi was still on. Happened with my class mate too. Better order a new one, RIP cam.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

This command helps in enabling camera access. You may try this.